# Unenroll Moodle users in a category using SQL

Tags: mysql, moodle

I need to **unenroll** all the **users** at once **from all the courses** in a specific **category** (chosen by name or shortname) in my **moodle** site. 
I think that a SQL statement is the way to do this.

Courses aren't empty so delete all the courses is no option.

Thank you

Comment: Inspect database schema of you moodle version: https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Database_Schema. Come back with tables involved and you will get faster response.

Comment: Direct SQL statements are usually a very bad idea, you need to use the Moodle API.

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested the following solution, but it should produce the desired effect:

```
require($CFG->libdir . '/coursecatlib.php');
require($CFG->libdir . '/enrollib.php');

$categoryid = 0;    // Replace with the desired category ID.
$category = coursecat::get($categoryid);
foreach ($category->get_courses() as $course) {
    // Simulates the deletion of the course, a better solution is to copy
    // the logic from `enrol_course_delete` here directly.
    enrol_course_delete($course);
}
```

The above script can take a while so you should probably execute this from the command line.

You can loop over the sub-categories using:

```
$categories = $category->get_children();
foreach ($categories as $category) {
}
```

To obtain the ID of a category by shortname, use the following:

```
$name = "My category";
$categoryid = $DB->get_field('course_categories', 'id', array('name' => $name), MUST_EXIST);
```

Note that categories can have identical names, you should use the category `idnumber` instead.

Answer (score 1):

It will be very complicated to do this via SQL because there are lots of enrol plugins. Each might have its own set of data.

If you take a look at the `function reset_course_userdata` in `/lib/moodlelib.php` there is this section of code. Try modifying this for what you need.

```
$plugins = enrol_get_plugins(true);
$instances = enrol_get_instances($data->courseid, true);
foreach ($instances as $key => $instance) {
    if (!isset($plugins[$instance->enrol])) {
        unset($instances[$key]);
        continue;
    }
}

foreach ($data->unenrol_users as $withroleid) {
    if ($withroleid) {
        $sql = "SELECT ue.*
                  FROM {user_enrolments} ue
                  JOIN {enrol} e ON (e.id = ue.enrolid AND e.courseid = :courseid)
                  JOIN {context} c ON (c.contextlevel = :courselevel AND c.instanceid = e.courseid)
                  JOIN {role_assignments} ra ON (ra.contextid = c.id AND ra.roleid = :roleid AND ra.userid = ue.userid)";
        $params = array('courseid' => $data->courseid, 'roleid' => $withroleid, 'courselevel' => CONTEXT_COURSE);

    } else {
        // Without any role assigned at course context.
        $sql = "SELECT ue.*
                  FROM {user_enrolments} ue
                  JOIN {enrol} e ON (e.id = ue.enrolid AND e.courseid = :courseid)
                  JOIN {context} c ON (c.contextlevel = :courselevel AND c.instanceid = e.courseid)
             LEFT JOIN {role_assignments} ra ON (ra.contextid = c.id AND ra.userid = ue.userid)
                 WHERE ra.id IS null";
        $params = array('courseid' => $data->courseid, 'courselevel' => CONTEXT_COURSE);
    }

    $rs = $DB->get_recordset_sql($sql, $params);
    foreach ($rs as $ue) {
        if (!isset($instances[$ue->enrolid])) {
            continue;
        }
        $instance = $instances[$ue->enrolid];
        $plugin = $plugins[$instance->enrol];
        if (!$plugin->allow_unenrol($instance) and !$plugin->allow_unenrol_user($instance, $ue)) {
            continue;
        }

        $plugin->unenrol_user($instance, $ue->userid);
        $data->unenrolled[$ue->userid] = $ue->userid;
    }
    $rs->close();
}
```